# Perl - Store regex formula in a variable and then use this to match a regex

Tags: regex, perl, variables, match

I have a file, which contains long lines like this:

```
XEP.101     :1804 000000:I:XEPInfoFormat:Status=ok:TID=00000000516F6161-000874C3-00003E19-62F2B0C6:CallType=gprs:CallStart=20130415210553:CallDuration=4334:ServedParty=724044024363999:ServedLocation=724:OtherParty=TIM:OtherLocation=tim.br:ServedZone=ZO00001:OtherZone=ZP32363:TariffZone=ZN1261:CUST_ID=58922505:CO_ID=58891164:account=8327813:MSISDN=554599836655:theoretical_cost_value=33.323525:BA_Line_Main_value=NA:Tariff=TM_PL5PR:FU_Packs_used=FU_PLWI2:SNCODE_FU=1350_1250_1_BA_FU_PLWI2_Byt_Internet2:MCs_used=NO:bcd=20100319,bcp=P1M:InputFilename=201304172345.000020:EipFilename=/gold/rte/data/RatedEvents/EIP/10/101201304172345.000020:RtxFilename=/gold/rte/data/RatedEvents/RTX/01/OPSCGOLD_20130418000000_1011917.xml:BadrateFilename=/gold/rte/data/BadRate/bad_rate_xep10.201304172345.000020.tmp:FILE=/gold/rte/data/IncomingCDRs/ASN1/010/GPRS99+GPRS99-46299-1304172357-SA.TTF;TICKET=660
```

So I have this condition, to match this line in Perl:

```
if ( $line =~ m/XEP.[0-9].*:(\d{4}) (\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*XEPInfoFormat:Status=(\w*):TID=(\S*):CallType=(\w*):CallStart=(\d*):CallDuration=(\d*):ServedParty=(\d*):ServedLocation=(\d*):OtherParty=(\w*):OtherLocation=(\w*):ServedZone=(\w*):OtherZone=(\w*):TariffZone=(\w*):CUST_ID=(\d*):CO_ID=(\d*):account=(\d*):MSISDN=(\d*):theoretical_cost_value=(\d*)\.(\d*):BA_Line_Main_value=(\w*):Tariff=(\w*):FU_Packs_used=(\w*):SNCODE_FU=(\w*):MCs_used=(\w*):bcd=(\d*),bcp=(\w*):InputFilename=(\d*)\.(\d*):EipFilename=\/\w*\/\w*\/\w*\/\w*\/\w*\/(\d*)\/(\d*)\.(\d*).*FILE=\/\w*\/\w*\/\w*\/\w*\/\w*\/(\d*)\/(\w*)\+(\w*)-(\d*)-(\d*)-(\w*).(\w*);TICKET=(\d*)/ ) {
```

So for me that's ok, this is matching and bringing me the results.
However, I'd like to make it more flexible, for example, if I'd like to match this whole line and specify a field in my match as an option in my script, e.g. (contains before TID=), so, what I'm trying to do is:

```
use Getopt::Std;
getopts("Ch:t:",\%opts);

if ( $opts{t} ) {
    $TIDS = $opts{t};
} else {
    $TIDS = '/S*';
}
```

So, I'm trying to do like this, my match substitute with variable $TIDS, using getopts -t

```
if ( $line =~ m/XEP.[0-9].*:(\d{4}) (\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*XEPInfoFormat:Status=(\w*):TID=(${TIDS})
```

So, if I specify a parameter with -t option, like:

```
perl-script.pl -t 888894343
```

I'd like that it matches like this in my whole regex:

```
if ( $line =~ m/XEP.[0-9].*:(\d{4}) (\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*XEPInfoFormat:Status=(\w*):TID=(888894343)
```

But, if I do not specify this, I'd like that it matches like this:

```
if ( $line =~ m/XEP.[0-9].*:(\d{4}) (\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*XEPInfoFormat:Status=(\w*):TID=(/S*)
```

I know that I could simply match all lines with (/S*), and then put some simple if condition like below, but this way I lose performance because there's a lot of lines like the one I gave as example, so I'd like to have a flexible match with

```
print "$line\n" if $6 eq $TIDS;
```

Does anybody have any ideas? I tried use quotemeta, put in simple quotes, double quotes my regex but did not worked.

Comment: You can only do substitutions inside the regexp delimiters, a substitution can't supply the delimiters themselves (perl parses the regexp first, then interpolate variables into it). And you're missing the closing delimiter entirely in the first version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use quotemeta on a variable such as a command line argument, you'd need to do something like:

```
$foo = quotemeta($ARGV[0]);
```

Comment: Well, i didn't get it using quotemeta. I used something like this:


    if ( $opts{t} ) {
        $TIDS = $opts{t};
    } else {
        $TIDS = "\\S\*";
    }

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your code doesn't work is that you are using `'/S*'`, which matches a slash followed by zero or more `S` characters, instead of `'\S*'`, which is zero or more whitespace characters.

However, rather than using a regular expression I think it would be better to split each record into fields using `split /:/`. Furthermore, all of the fields after the first four are of the for `name=value`, so these can conveniently be put into a hash for easy access. Then all you have to do is check `if ($ch{t} eq $params{TID}) { ... }`.

This code demonstrates. I have used `Data::Dump` to display the contents of the `%params` hash that is built. It's not clear whether the information in those first four fields is significant, but I have extracted them into `@params` in case you need them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my %opts = (t => 888894343);

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  my %params = $line =~ /([^:=]+)=([^:=]+)/g;
  ddx \%params;
  #next if $opts{t} and $params{TID} ne $opts{t};
  my @params = (split /:/, $line, 5)[0..3];
  ddx \@params;
  #print $line;
}

__DATA__
XEP.101     :1804 000000:I:XEPInfoFormat:Status=ok:TID=00000000516F6161-000874C3-00003E19-62F2B0C6:CallType=gprs:CallStart=20130415210553:CallDuration=4334:ServedParty=724044024363999:ServedLocation=724:OtherParty=TIM:OtherLocation=tim.br:ServedZone=ZO00001:OtherZone=ZP32363:TariffZone=ZN1261:CUST_ID=58922505:CO_ID=58891164:account=8327813:MSISDN=554599836655:theoretical_cost_value=33.323525:BA_Line_Main_value=NA:Tariff=TM_PL5PR:FU_Packs_used=FU_PLWI2:SNCODE_FU=1350_1250_1_BA_FU_PLWI2_Byt_Internet2:MCs_used=NO:bcd=20100319,bcp=P1M:InputFilename=201304172345.000020:EipFilename=/gold/rte/data/RatedEvents/EIP/10/101201304172345.000020:RtxFilename=/gold/rte/data/RatedEvents/RTX/01/OPSCGOLD_20130418000000_1011917.xml:BadrateFilename=/gold/rte/data/BadRate/bad_rate_xep10.201304172345.000020.tmp:FILE=/gold/rte/data/IncomingCDRs/ASN1/010/GPRS99+GPRS99-46299-1304172357-SA.TTF;TICKET=660
```

**output**

```
# para.pl:11: {
#   account                => 8327813,
#   BA_Line_Main_value     => "NA",
#   BadrateFilename        => "/gold/rte/data/BadRate/bad_rate_xep10.201304172345.000020.tmp",
#   bcd                    => "20100319,bcp",
#   CallDuration           => 4334,
#   CallStart              => 20130415210553,
#   CallType               => "gprs",
#   CO_ID                  => 58891164,
#   CUST_ID                => 58922505,
#   EipFilename            => "/gold/rte/data/RatedEvents/EIP/10/101201304172345.000020",
#   FILE                   => "/gold/rte/data/IncomingCDRs/ASN1/010/GPRS99+GPRS99-46299-1304172357-SA.TTF;TICKET",
#   FU_Packs_used          => "FU_PLWI2",
#   InputFilename          => "201304172345.000020",
#   MCs_used               => "NO",
#   MSISDN                 => 554599836655,
#   OtherLocation          => "tim.br",
#   OtherParty             => "TIM",
#   OtherZone              => "ZP32363",
#   RtxFilename            => "/gold/rte/data/RatedEvents/RTX/01/OPSCGOLD_20130418000000_1011917.xml",
#   ServedLocation         => 724,
#   ServedParty            => 724044024363999,
#   ServedZone             => "ZO00001",
#   SNCODE_FU              => "1350_1250_1_BA_FU_PLWI2_Byt_Internet2",
#   Status                 => "ok",
#   Tariff                 => "TM_PL5PR",
#   TariffZone             => "ZN1261",
#   theoretical_cost_value => 33.323525,
#   TID                    => "00000000516F6161-000874C3-00003E19-62F2B0C6",
# }
# para.pl:14: ["    XEP.101     ", "1804 000000", "I", "XEPInfoFormat"]
```

Comment: It's quite interesting your solution proposal, i'll think about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion. There is no need to check the value of `TID` and parse the line in one go: you can do a very fast check of the record first and then parse (using either the hash technique or using a regex as you choose) it if it is of interest.

```
while (<>) {
  next if $opts{t} and $line !~ /:TID=$opts{t}:/;
  # Parse and process record
}
```

Comment: Humm... it's because by intentions is put each match each field in my line be flexible to put it in getopts, so i think i need another solution